# Mixins may not be defined within control directives or other mixins

Tags: node-sass

I try to install npm packages. All packages install properly.
But when I try to run application using `npm start` at that time below error occurs:

> ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":[]}!./src/styles.scss
>   Module build failed:
>   undefined
>   ^
>   Mixins may not be defined within control directives or other mixins.
>   in
>   D:\DailyJS\CIDE_SCHOOL_DEV\node_modules\@angular\material_theming.scss
>   (line 2440, column 10)
>   Error:
>   undefined
>   ^
>   Mixins may not be defined within control directives or other mixins.
>   in
>   D:\DailyJS\CIDE_SCHOOL_DEV\node_modules\@angular\material_theming.scss
>   (line 2440, column 10)
>   at options.error
>   (D:\DailyJS\CIDE_SCHOOL_DEV\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:291:26)
>   @ ./src/styles.scss 4:14-187
>   @ multi ./node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss
>   ./src/styles.scss
>   webpack: Failed to compile.

I don't know why this happens?
Previously I cloned the repository from Github, and then installed npm packages by using `npm install`. Then it worked.

But today, it gives this error:

> Mixins may not be defined within control directives or other mixins.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Now, i found the solution there was an issue with node-sass pacakge.
so install the

*`npm i node-sass@4.8.1`*

package then it works.

Comment: It is working now, and the package is found fine. Thanks.